# HQL query for Distinct records

Tags: java, hql

pls i get this error any time i run my application ....any help pls.

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!
        org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.NodeTraverser.traverseDepthFirst(NodeTraverser.java:63)
        org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:272)
        org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:180)
        org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
        org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
        org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
        org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:119)


org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:214)
        org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:192)
        org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1537)
        org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:285)
        sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

this is the code i av in my repository class

```
@Query("distinct v from voucher v where v.voucherType.typeID = :typeID ")
       public List<Voucher> findDistinctByVoucherType(@Param("typeID") Long voucherTypeId);
```

Comment: Remove v from select class

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with query. The above exception indicates that

```
distinct v from voucher v where v.voucherType.typeID = :typeID
```

is not returning any result